# When add 1 the string should not is 01

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am try add 1, but `item.num` is  01. How to add 1 input value is 1,2,3,4,5...? Note that `num` must be the string. Go the demo of [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhouyulong/amhjf8u9/1/).

#### Look at the gif:

[image]

#### Look at the image:

[image]

#### Note:`item.num += 1` do not need to modify!

[image]

#### I want the following effect:

[image]

#### Look at the javascript:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    list: [{
      id: "1",
      name: "demo01",
      num: "0"
    }],
    addnum: []
  },
  methods: {
    addClick(item) {
      console.log(this.addnum.push(item))
      item.num+=1
    },

  }
})
```

#### HTML file:

```
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in list">
      <p>{{item.name}}</p>
      <br>
      <input type="text" :value="item.num">
      <button @click="addClick(item)">+</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not simply coercing first? Have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/9knrb919/ Also, why a string in the first place? Just use a number: https://jsfiddle.net/pb9u3umh/

Comment: You should first convert item.num to a number

Comment: hi, you should use a for loop increment for this function

Comment: something like this or (var i = 0; i < var.length; i++)

Comment: can you explain where these limitations come from? Why does this number have to be a string? And why can't you modify a simple line of code in your own component? In the current context and code, these requirements make no sense to me.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Your code seems really confusing.

Comment: @Thomas Because it is a string returned by JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hoping that you can at least add some code to `addClick` method, here's what to do:

```
addClick(item) {
      console.log(this.addnum.push(item))
      item.num = parseInt(item.num, 10)
      item.num+=1
      item.num = ""+item.num // converting back to string
    },
```